# Generalize distribution of class from manually labelled pattern to whole dataset

Tags: inference

So I have a big dataset of M examples, I've randomly draw N examples from it and manually labelled them. A percentage of X of these N examples are labelled negative.

Given this, I want to say with a margin of error E, that the whole dataset reproduces the pattern found in this subset of N examples.

If this isn't possible, there's anything that I can say about this subset and it's generalization for the whole dataset?

This looks like statistical inference to me, but I don't know how to search for this. None of the traditional tests like Student's or Z test don't seem appropriate for this.